# How do you get a UIPageViewController to work when rotated to landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

In [this tutorial on UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) (there's a download for the project at the bottom) the author sets up a great `UIPageViewController` that works flawlessly in portrait mode.

But it goes completely awry when rotating to landscape. The image is pushed to the bottom left corner, and in general it's just completely messed up.

I cannot figure out how on earth to solve this issue. I've searched and searched, and no example projects seem to work in landscape. What do I need to do in order to make it work in landscape?

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented UIPageViewController in my most recent project so here's a snapshot of some of the properties I'm using to set it up correctly. Essentially, it's the placement of the spine location that is probably messing up your display. Try playing with the different values (i.e. None, Mid, Min, Max) and see what works for you.

[image: UIPageViewController landscape properties]

Comment: How does this work with rotation, though? It seems this is hardcoded to landscape. I need to be able to switch back and forth between portrait and landscape.

Comment: I would recommend listening for when the orientation changes and changing your spine location accordingly.

Comment: I'm indeed using `pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:` but it's still not working whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

`PageContentViewController` in that tutorial has no layout constraints applied to its views.

For `UIImageView` I set space to superview in each direction.
For `UILabel` I set space to superview in each direction except bottom.

Now image is stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Try following settings. It may help you.

[image]

[image]